# Prevent each word from being a single character with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've been checking strings with this regex until now.

`^[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]{1,}(?:\s{1}[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]{1,})+$`

This is a regex that allows the following examples.

- Apple Banana
- A Banana
- A. Banana
- Apple B
  etc...

But I want prevent both word from being single charackter like this.

- A B

For example

- A Banana => This is ok.
- Apple B => This is ok.
- A B => This is NOT ok.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assert that the string contains 2 chars from the character class (without the `.`) and shorten the `{1,}` to `+`

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ]{2})[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]+(?:\s[a-zA-ZöÖşŞçÇüÜıİğĞ.]+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pl2zqi/1)